# skip the cells with -9999 and perform multiple regression

Tags: r

I want to do a multiple regression where SMDI is my dependent variable and others are my independent variables. Here's the data.

```
d <- read.table(text="SMDI  ET  PRCP    ET_Ch   PRCP_Ch
    -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
    -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
    -9999   621 11.20291    -111    -58.568
    1.067062    -9999   9.049039    -9999   -61.8191
    2.647571    551 7.778518    -113    -61.5458
    0.962622    475 10.32385    -145    -54.0697
    -9999   -9999   13.5475 -9999   -40.8121
    -9999   -9999   13.60227    -9999   -45.3488
    -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
    -9999   -9999   18.98804    -9999   -45.5135
    -9999   594 14.24568    -119    -61.0664
    1.061673    471 10.34461    -129    -71.1407
    0.535265    420 9.74108 -137    -73.3488
    0.010328    420 10.97725    -144    -69.031
    0.132918    418 11.02256    -135    -60.2483
    0.647663    397 11.98954    -134    -57.1096
    -9999   -9999   12.0852 -9999   -46.0085
    -9999   -9999   23.51045    -9999   -46.0736
    -9999   691 17.06862    -108    -63.3729",
header=TRUE)
```

Regression Code

```
lm(SMDI ~ ET + ET_Ch + PRCP + PRCP_Ch, data=d)
```

My data uses `-9999` as the code for missing, so as is, the result I get is incorrect. What code should I add so that if any of the cell in the table contains `-9999`, it skips that and only considers the cells that does not contain `-9999` values?

Comment: do you mean that you want to treat the -9999 as missing or you literally want to remove them and shift all the other subsequent values up. the first one is easy, use `na.strings = '-9999'` in read.table

Comment: I would say consider as missing data, if i remove the -9999, the rows and column number would be different in each headings that creates problem in calculating regression.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would like to subset your data based on the -9999 value (i.e. remove rows where any row value is -9999. If this is true, the following code will do that. Someone will probably also suggest a `dplyr` or `data.table` solution to the problem that is cleaner.

```
inds=unique(unlist(apply(d,2,function(x){which(x == -9999)})))
d2 = d[-inds,]
```

If you mean that you want to treat -9999 as missing values, then simply change the -9999 to `NA` and set the appropriate `na.action` item.

```
 d[d==-9999]=NA
```

Comment: Instead of the complex apply statement, check out `complete.cases`, which could be used after setting to `NA`.